# SQL CLR generated file in wrong order

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, publish, sqlclr

I have a very simple SQL Project in Visual Studio 2013 but cannot publish to another database.

Within the obj folder it generates the "MYPROJECT.generated.sql" file, but the Microsoft.SqlServer.Server attributes are outputted above the CREATE ASSEMBLY.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ....
AS EXTERNAL NAME [MyProject].[StoredProcedures].[MyMethod]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER ....
FOR INSERT
AS EXTERNAL NAME [MyProject].[Triggers].[MyTrigger]
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [MyProject] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x234234...... (DLL as Binary Hex)
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

My problem is that this generates an error because the [MyProject] was not found in the SQL catalog.  If I manually move the CREATE ASSEMBLY to the top then it works as desired.

I assume a T4 template is generating this file and was wondering if anyone knows how to update/swap the template so that I can shuffle the order (and perhaps add schema to the SqlProcedureAttribute)

[UPDATE]

My target database takes 30min to publish and I need a faster turn around for developing/debugging SQLCLR projects.  My SQLCLR is a separate project that is set as a dependency from my large target database (build order).  In the interim I've created a vbScript that is invoked in the SQLCLR post build event to copy the SQLCLR/prebuild.sql and combine the bottom of generated.sql + top of generated.sql + SQLCLR/postbuild.sql into a consolidated Target/PostBuild.sql.  These two scripts are fired from the pre and post build scripts of the target database.  This ensures that my assembly hex is current and targets the proper configuration (DEBUG|RELEASE) and I can manually deploy it outside of the target project.  (3 seconds vs 30 minutes to redeploy my assembly)

[UPDATE2]

I'm modified it from generating a scripts to attach to the main project, to a standalone project with linked files.  This way the large database project deployment remains unchanged and deployed with dacpac, and I have a separate project that I can use for fast build and deploy testing